# Change EasyEngine 3.x admin password manually?

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, easy-engine

The recommended way to update the admin password with EasyEngine is as follows:

`ee auth update --user=someName --password=somePassword`

Unfortunately EasyEngine no longer works as intended the the `ee` command is broken. Is there some other way we can modify the authentication username/password?

I checked the SQLite database located at, `/var/lib/ee/ee.db` but it doesn't relate to the authentication details unfortunately. I'm not sure where else this could be stored and how it could be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give up and move to [WordOps](https://wordops.net/).

Not a great answer, but my answer. That said, WordOps is pretty fantastic so I have no qualms with the final outcome. It did take a day instead of a minute though...